Identify the first child from root for all leaf nodes in a child-parent table
I have this table
emp_no  unq_key          emp_id          mgr_id
7518870 2244087948  2244087965  2244087948
7518870 2244087948  2333920909  2244087948
7518870 2244087948  2244087950  2244087948
7518870 2244087948  2244087948  2340921616
7518870 2244087948  2244087963  2244087948
7518870 2244087948  2244087962  2244087961
7518870 2244087948  2244088015  2244087951
7518870 2244087948  2358036768  2244087955
7518870 2244087948  2244087952  2244087951
7518870 2244087948  2244087953  2244087952
7518870 2244087948  2244460352  2244087965
7518870 2244087948  2244087957  2244087948
7518870 2244087948  2277248665  2277248664
7518870 2244087948  2277248667  2244087965
7518870 2244087948  2340921670  2244087955
7518870 2244087948  2244087959  2244087948
7518870 2244087948  2244087960  2244087948
7518870 2244087948  2352651692  2244087951
7518870 2244087948  2314063120  2244087955
7518870 2244087948  2244088014  2244087952
7518870 2244087948  2244087954  2244087951
7518870 2244087948  2244087956  2244087955
7518870 2244087948  2244087955  2244087951
7518870 2244087948  2277248664  2244087951
7518870 2244087948  2280898236  2277248645
7518870 2244087948  2277248645  2244087951
7518870 2244087948  2358036769  2244087948
7518870 2244087948  2244087958  2244087948
7518870 2244087948  2244088016  2244088015
7518870 2244087948  2244087951  2244087948

My root record is unq_key=emp_id. I am trying to print the first respective emp_id child for all leaf nodes. I am trying to identify with below code but not getting proper first child.
eg: 2244088016 is the leaf node with first child : 2244087951
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

;WITH   tree_view AS (
    SELECT 
         emp_no
         ,unq_key
         ,emp_id
         ,mgr_id
         ,0 AS order_sequence
         ,0 AS generation_number
          
    FROM 
        #temp_employees
    WHERE 
        unq_key=emp_id 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            parent.emp_no,
             parent.unq_key,
             parent.emp_id,
             parent.mgr_id 
             ,order_sequence +1 AS order_sequence
             ,generation_number + 1 AS generation_number
        FROM 
            #temp_employees parent
            JOIN tree_view tv
          ON parent.mgr_id = tv.emp_id
    ) 
    SELECT
       RIGHT('------------',generation_number*3) + ' Emp :'+ cast( emp_id as varchar(100))
      ,*
    FROM 
        tree_view   
    ORDER BY order_sequence; 

Just need an additional column with the first child.

If I were you I would provide a DBFiddle so people can test your query and fix it. it's unlikely anyone will type all that data in

Easy peasy to convert by simply pasting to ChatGPT and ask to convert to DDL and DML statements. DbFiddle here.. The question itself, though, isn't very clear.

You need to define clearly what you mean by leaf node and first child

I interpreted "first child" to mean "given the path from the root to each leaf, find the first node after the root". In other words, for the root node there is no first child, and for all direct children of the root the first child is itself.
If that's correct, here's a solution which makes use of a closure table. A closure table contains an edge from every node to every other node in its lineage (not just to its parent, but also its parent's parent, etc, all the way to the root), and the distance is the length of the edge between the nodes.
Note that in order to do this, the recursive CTE starts from "everyone" rather than starting at the root.
with emps as
(
   select   *
   from     (
               values
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087965, 2244087948),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2333920909, 2244087948),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087950, 2244087948),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087948, 2340921616),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087963, 2244087948),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087962, 2244087961),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244088015, 2244087951),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2358036768, 2244087955),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087952, 2244087951),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087953, 2244087952),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244460352, 2244087965),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087957, 2244087948),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2277248665, 2277248664),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2277248667, 2244087965),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2340921670, 2244087955),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087959, 2244087948),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087960, 2244087948),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2352651692, 2244087951),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2314063120, 2244087955),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244088014, 2244087952),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087954, 2244087951),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087956, 2244087955),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087955, 2244087951),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2277248664, 2244087951),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2280898236, 2277248645),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2277248645, 2244087951),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2358036769, 2244087948),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087958, 2244087948),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244088016, 2244088015),
                  (7518870, 2244087948, 2244087951, 2244087948)
            ) t (emp_no, unq_key, emp_id, mgr_id)
),
closure as
(
      select   emp_id      = emp_id,
               mgr_id      = emp_id,             
               emp_no,
               unq_key,
               distance = 0
      from     emps
      union all
      select   e.emp_id,
               c.mgr_id,            
               e.emp_no,
               e.unq_key,
               c.distance + 1
      from     emps     e
      join     closure  c on c.emp_id = e.mgr_id
)

select      tree = concat(replicate('-', tree.distance * 3), ' Emp :', tree.emp_id),    
            e.*,
            first_child = tier1.mgr_id
from        (select * from closure where mgr_id = unq_key) tree
join        emps e on e.emp_id = tree.emp_id
left join   closure tier1 on tier1.emp_id = tree.emp_id and tier1.distance = tree.distance - 1
order by    tier1.mgr_id, tree.distance;

The tree subquery is used to get just the rows in the closure table that represent the edges from each node to the root. The distance of those rows provides the required level of indenting.
This is joined back to emps just to include all of the original columns from the source data.
The tier1 left join then finds the edge for that node where the edge distance is one less than the distance to the root.
I have a nagging intuition that this can be simplified but my brain doesn't seem to be firing on all cylinders at the moment.
